# Is there a way to provide a single macro function to return values of different types including nothing?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have created the following macros to lock a mutex and return (from the function within which this macro is called) in case the attempt at locking fails. Currently I have narrowed it down to 2 macros - one for returning from functions which do return a value, irrespective of type, and another for returning from functions which return nothing (i.e. *void*).

*The code beyond the macros (below) is for illustration only and has very little to do with the actual production code that the macros will be used in.*

```
#define MUTEX_LOCK()\
    {\
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0)\
        {\
            printf("Failed to lock mutex.\n");\
            return;\
        }\
    }
#define MUTEX_LOCK_RVAL(err_val)\
    {\
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0)\
        {\
            printf("Failed to lock mutex.\n");\
            return err_val;\
        }\
    }

void vfunc()
{
    printf("\nIn vfunc()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK();
    printf("\nOut of vfunc()\n");
}

UINT16 uint16func()
{
    printf("\nIn uint16func()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK_RVAL(0);
    printf("\nOut of uint16func()\n");

    return 9;
}

CHAR* errstr = "Hoo boy!";
CHAR* strfunc()
{
    printf("\nIn strfunc()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK_RVAL(errstr);
    printf("\nOut of strfunc()\n");

    return NULL;
}
```

Is there a way to reduce these to a single macro that can be used in functions returning a value as well as *void*.

Comment: Function-like macros that contain a return... that's really really nasty. Forget about it, just use `if (!my_lock()) return <whatever>;` at the call sites, with a proper lock function.

Comment: It might be possible using e.g. [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro), but there are caveats. And it will really be confusing for other readers of your code (and with "others" I include you in a year or so).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you expect the calls to be confusing, or only the macro definition? If only the latter, some judicious comments should solve it, no?

Comment: Oh, and you macros in their current incarnation contains *undefined behavior* as you compare the return value of `pthread_mutex_lock` with *uninitialized local variables*. You don't need the variables at all actually, and I really recommend you think about what @Mat is saying, then you can have a single macro that is a simple expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Variadic macros is out of the question since I am restricted to strict C90.

Comment: @Mat - The desire is to avoid repetition of the print and the return value. This makes the code look 'nicer', also there a lot fewer lines of code as a result of the maros.

Comment: You put the print in the lock function, no need to repeat that. Hiding the return statement is _not_ a win if the only thing it saves you a few keystrokes. Remember you write code once, but read it many times. Saving a few characters is a bad idea if it means your function's control flow has become invisible.

Comment: Does my answer fulfill your expectations? Could you take a brief look at it, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it ANSI compatible I define the macro with return and another simple symbol that evaluates to null and is clearly showing that it is null.
I.e.:

```
#define VOID_RET    //This nulls the return value
#define MUTEX_LOCK(err_val)\
    {\
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0)\
        {\
            printf("Failed to lock mutex.\n");\
            return err_val;\
        }\
    }
void *mutex = NULL;
void vfunc(void)
{
    printf("\nIn vfunc()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK(VOID_RET);
    printf("\nOut of vfunc()\n");
}
UINT16 uint16func(void)
{
    printf("\nIn uint16func()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK(0);
    printf("\nOut of uint16func()\n");

    return 9;
}
CHAR* errstr = "Hoo boy!";
CHAR* strfunc(void)
{
    printf("\nIn strfunc()\n");
    MUTEX_LOCK(errstr);
    printf("\nOut of strfunc()\n");

    return NULL;
}
```

I tested this code under C11 and C99.

Comment: Anyway, this is much nicer than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the documentation, you can remove the macro function taking no argument because you are not obligated to pass an argument at all to a macro function expecting arguments.
From the [GNU GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html):

> You can leave macro arguments empty; this is not an error to the
>   preprocessor [...]

---

For multiple arguments, this is interesting:

> You cannot leave out arguments entirely; if a macro takes two
>   arguments, there must be exactly one comma at the top level of its
>   argument list.

With these examples given:

```
min(, b)        ==> ((   ) < (b) ? (   ) : (b))
min(a, )        ==> ((a  ) < ( ) ? (a  ) : ( ))
min(,)          ==> ((   ) < ( ) ? (   ) : ( ))
min((,),)       ==> (((,)) < ( ) ? ((,)) : ( ))
```

Comment: I had tried this, but this isn't valid ansi C (I compile with the **-pedantic and -Werror** flags). I get the error *empty macro arguments are undefined in ISO C90 and ISO C++98*.

Comment: @work.bin Could you tell me why you're bound to these old standards? At least C99 should be default nowadays, IMO.

Comment: You wish! But there aren't too many compilers supporting C99. If portability is a concern then you are limited to C90.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution i can imagine is this:

```
#define MUTEX_LOCK( err_val )\
{\
  {\
      if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0)\
      {\
          printf("Failed to lock mutex.\n");\
          return err_val;\
      }\
   }\
}

int test_int()
{
    MUTEX_LOCK( 1 );

    return 0;
}

void test_void()
{
    MUTEX_LOCK( ; );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Not particularly elegant, but clever. This does answer my question but I am not sure if I will use this.